# Why would A-Train be reported as having won this race?

Tags: the-boys

In *The Boys* Season one Episode three, A-Train is announced as having won the race - but he lost. According to the scoreboard, his opponent was faster than him.[image: Image1][image: Image2]

Answer (score 11):

## Because he did.

If you look closely the numbers you are seeing are **speeds** not time.

A-Train's speed is 371 meters per second (m/s) but ShoCkwave's was only 342 m/s in the same time.

[image]

Comment: Oh my gosh I'm a genius - I thought that was a measure of Milliseconds. Thanks.

Comment: It couldn't be since the elapsed time is there are the same for both.

Comment: @Hellreaver - milli-seconds would just be "ms", not "m/s"